# How to assign variable from grep output in a while loop

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, grep

I wanted to create a variable for each grep regex line from Usernames.txt file.
The text contains this

```
mario,visitor
bobmarley,staff
luigi,visitor
hailey,visitor
```

and so on.

I want the name from before the comma as a username and visitor as the group for the user

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo addgroup visitor
sudo addgroup staff

filename='Usernames.txt'

while read line; do
username=$(echo $line | grep -o '^[a-z]*[^,]')
group=$(echo $line | grep -o '[^,][a-z]*$')
sudo useradd $username -G $group -p $username
done < $filename
```

but the output says command username not found.
So instead I tried not so efficient method

```sh
while read line; do
sudo useradd $(echo $line | grep -o '^[a-z]*[^,]') -G $(echo $line | grep -o '[^,][a-z]*$') -p $(echo $line | grep -o '^[a-z]*[^,]')
done < $filename
```

I want the result of each loop to be like this

```
sudo useradd mario -G visitor -p mario
```

How do I improve this? Thanks!

Comment: _I wanted to create a variable for each_ : You will end up having many variables. Wouldn't it make more sense to create an array?

Comment: You can do the splitting on the comma inside the `read` statement, by setting `IFS=,`. No need to start two _grep_ child processes for each input line.

Comment: I see, I'm still very new to bash scripting so I don't know much about the syntaxes available in bash. I usually do full stack web dev using javascript so yeah @user1934428.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forking of multiple processes (e.g. `grep`) on every single loop iteration is a bad idea in general. Also, simple word splitting can be done directly in Bash, without any external processes.

Option 1:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
  username="${line%,*}"
  group="${line#*,}"
  echo sudo useradd "$username" -G "$group" -p "$username"
done < "$filename"
```

Option 2:

```sh
while IFS=, read -r username group; do
  echo sudo useradd "$username" -G "$group" -p "$username"
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: Indeed it is, nice

Comment: Thank you! IFS seems like a very useful syntax. From what i have researched, IFS is used to preserve white space. What will it do when you put stuff other than , after IFS= ? Will it just replace it with space?

Comment: The input field separator just determines how the input is split into tokens. `IFS=,` makes a comma work like white space. Setting the `IFS` to an empty value (as in the first example) has no relevance for this particular case, but yes, it would preserve all white space if there was some on the line. I usually set `IFS=` and `-r` even when no spaces and no backslashes are expected, just to make the script more reusable and to reveal odd issues with the input as early as possible (e.g. trailing white space).

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach

```
while read -r name role; do
    sudo useradd $name -G $role -p $name
done < <(sed 's/,/ /' $filename)
```

Actually `sed` is enough:

```
sudo sed 's/\(.*\),\(.*\)/useradd \1 -G \2 -p \1/e' $filename
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer it works perfect! But just a few questions.
What does < < do? why does it need a space?

Comment: This is the syntax to redirect from command(sub shell) instead of file. It's needed to process file with sed and replace ',' to ' '. `Read` can read multiple vars provided via space separated string. Or you can change the file itself, replace ',' to ' ' than it'll be like in your first variant `... done < $filename`

Comment: I see! So with < < <(sed 's/,/ /' $filename) will also work right? Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Actually, `sed` is not needed at all.